# PHPExcel cannot print Chinese character

Tags: php, phpexcel

I know this question might be redundant, but I had to go through them and I cannot solve my problem. 
1 - The data is in the DB and stored in UTF-8 encoding.
2 - The connection charset also had been set to UTF8.
3 - Have tried manually encode the value to UTF8 encode while printing using encode_utf8($value) where the $value is the Chinese character.

I used PHP 5.621, and PHPExcel class from http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel .

The result is still showing the Chinese character as "èµ›ç»´ç½‘ç»œ".

I am not printing the result on the page. I am creating a new xlsx file and printing onto it. The Chinese character is unreadable on the xlsx file, not on the page. On the page yes I can use the meta charset. But the problem is in the xlsx file.

Any advice for the best solution?

Comment: you must have header header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); on the top. if still you do see chinese character make sure that you open file in utf-8 enocding mode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907384/4248328  And https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981929/4248328

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera that content type on the header is already been used, and it works for the page. But not when the data is printed on the xlsx file.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh that is for printing on the page. My problem is to print on the xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content is already UTF-8 and you encode it again you certainly will get broken characters.
So, just omit the third step.

I noticed some people with Non-Western had issues with XLSX/Excel-2077 too, maybe it's a bug. Check the [PHPExcel GitHub tracker](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20utf-8).